# What is restarting my laptop doing that the “sudo service network-manager restart” isn't?

Tags: wifi, internet, release-hera, surface-tablet

I’ve tried many things on many threads here and still can’t manage to get the wifi working when it randomly drops..

**No it is not my connection because I have the same issue at uni.**

When I reset the network manager it actually tries searching for access points but then quickly fails... it is so frustrating having to reset my laptop ( Microsoft Surface Book ) over and over..

I really want to use elementary OS but these WiFi issues are seriously bugging me. I thought by restarting the network manager and having it re-search for access points it would start working but it just says no access points available after 2 seconds. When I restart my laptop it finds the access point and connects IMMEDIATELY! What is the restart doing that the

```
$ sudo service network-manager restart
```

does not do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your Surface Book to work well with Linux you have to watch your Github project, there is a specific Kernel and drivers for Microsoft Surface

https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface

---

## From the Github README

### Instructions

1. (Prep) Install Dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt install git curl wget sed
   ```
2. Clone the linux-surface repo:

   ```
   git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface.git ~/linux-surface
   ```
3. Change directory to linux-surface repo:

   ```
   cd ~/linux-surface
   ```
4. Run setup script:

   ```
   sudo sh setup.sh
   ```
5. Reboot on installed kernel.

The setup script will handle installing the latest kernel for you. You can also choose to download any version you want and install yourself: Install the headers, kernel and libc-dev (make sure you cd to your download location first):

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-[VERSION].deb linux-image-[VERSION].deb linux-libc-dev-[VERSION].deb
```

---

For more informations please read all the README in the Github's project

Comment: Thank you so much! I just did this and Ill update if the wifi is still not working properly.

Comment: Everything is working great (except sometimes the touch screen wont work and i need to restart). The wifi is working now and I can undock the touchscreen... man this is great. Thank you! Gotta also say thanks to the guys that gave out the stuff for the kernel!

Comment: You are welcome, I hope you will enjoy of your elementary OS in your Surface.